# Is link time optimization in gcc 5.1 good enough to give up on inlining simple functions?

Tags: c++, gcc

Out of habit I often write function definitions inline for simple functions such as this (contrived example)

```
class PositiveInteger
{
private:
    long long unsigned m_i;
public:
    PositiveInteger (int i);
};

inline PositiveInteger :: PositiveInteger (int i)
: m_i (i)
{
    if (i < 0)
        throw "oops";
}
```

I generally like to separate interface files and implementation files but, nevertheless, this is my habit for those functions which the voice in my head tells me will probably be hit a lot in hot spots.

I know the advice is "profile first" and I agree but I could avoid a whole load of profiling effort if I knew *a priori* that the compiler would produce identical final object code whether functions like this were inlined at compilation or link time. (Also, I believe the injected profiling code itself can cause a change in timing which swamps the effect of very simple functions such as the one above.)

GCC 5.1 has just been released advertising LTO (link time optimization) improvements. How good are they really? What kinds of functions can I safely un-inline knowing the final executable will not be affected?

Comment: That code formatting... hurts... eyes.  `PositiveInteger::PositiveInteger` is the name of a thing.  It's qualified, but still just a single name.  Why do you put spaces in it?

Comment: I find the way you wrote it hurts *my* eyes, although I realise it's more common by far. Same argument as for putting whitespace anywhere else really.

Answer (score 1):

You already answered your own question: Unless you're targeting an embedded system of some sort with restricted resources, write the code for clarity and maintainability first. Then *if* performance isn't acceptable you can profile and target your efforts towards the actual hotspots. Think about it: If you write clearer code that takes an extra 250ns that's not noticeable in your use case then the extra time doesn't matter.

Comment: The premise is that it *will* happen to be significantly slower if the compiler doesn't inline it. If, however, I know the compiler *will* inline it then I can *stop thinking about it altogether*. Without profiling.

Answer (score 0):

GCC with LTO does cross-module inlining, so most of the time you should not see difference in code quality. Offline function declarations are also not duplicated across translation units and compile faster/produce smaller object files.

GCC's inlining heuristics however consider "inline" keyword as a hint that function is probably good to be inlined and increase limits on function size. Similarly it will take bit of extra hint for functions declared in the same translation unit as called.  For small functions like one in your example this should not however make any difference.